# How to solve out of memory java error when you dont have the code?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, threadpool, ctakes

I am running ctakes DictionaryBuilder on Windows 11

it is a Java application that comes with ctakes ( a medical tool)

anyway, when I try to run this application I get this error

I am just a user of this application and not a developer and I don't have the code.

i wonder if there is a way i can get the application run from my position as a user

here is the error i get

```
07 Aug 2023 14:51:25  INFO MrConsoParser - File Lines: 8734439 Concepts: 2605571  Texts: 4701014
07 Aug 2023 14:51:25  INFO DictionaryBuilder - Performing Poor man's WSD ...
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:453)
        at org.apache.ctakes.gui.dictionary.util.TextTokenizer.getTokens(TextTokenizer.java:168)
        at org.apache.ctakes.gui.dictionary.util.TextTokenizer.lambda$getTokenizedText$0(TextTokenizer.java:192)
        at org.apache.ctakes.gui.dictionary.util.TextTokenizer$$Lambda$175/0x00000239811c9338.apply(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1006)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
        at org.apache.ctakes.gui.dictionary.util.TextTokenizer.getTokenizedText(TextTokenizer.java:194)
        at org.apache.ctakes.gui.dictionary.util.TextTokenizer.getTokenizedText(TextTokenizer.java:174)
        at org.apache.ctakes.gui.dictionary.umls.Concept.cullExtensions(Concept.java:59)
        at org.apache.ctakes.gui.dictionary.DictionaryBuilder.removeWsdRarities(DictionaryBuilder.java:85)
        at org.apache.ctakes.gui.dictionary.DictionaryBuilder.parseAll(DictionaryBuilder.java:70)
        at org.apache.ctakes.gui.dictionary.DictionaryBuilder.buildDictionary(DictionaryBuilder.java:52)
        at org.apache.ctakes.gui.dictionary.MainPanel$DictionaryBuildRunner.run(MainPanel.java:207)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.runWith(Thread.java:1636)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

my java is like this

```
PS H:\__cTAKES\bin> java -version
java version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.2+9-78, mixed mode, sharing)
PS H:\__cTAKES\bin>
```

Comment: You can tell `java` to use more memory, using runtime flags. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java.

Comment: If that fails (e.g. you can't make the heap any bigger), talk to the people who support the software you are trying to use.   This is not a programming question.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that link really helped me.
Thanks